# Push data to object angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I want to make tab of object, and pass to this tab values of another object using for loop. My tab of object:

```
data4 = [{meal_id : '' ,amount : '' }]
```

for loop:

```
for i in [0...$scope.mealsList.length]
            data4[i].meal_id = $scope.mealsList[i].id 
            data4[i].amount = $scope.mealsList[i].amount
```

`$scope.mealsList` is tab of objects, which i want to copy.

Now i have an error:

```
Cannot set property 'meal_id' of undefined
```

Can You tell me, what am i doing wrong?

ps: sorry for my language skills, hope you understand all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You iterate over the length of `$scope.mealsList` but get the values from data4. If those are not the same length (which seems to be the issue) you will get undefined when dereferencing `data[i]`.

I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but it seems like you want to modify $scope.mealsList into data4 since you are replacing all values of data4.

In that case you could just modify the values in the mealsList to what you want and set data4 to it.

```
var result = map($scope.mealsList, function(item) { return { meal_id: item.id, amount: item.amount };});
console.log('mapped: ', result);
data4 = result;

function map(arr, fn) {
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    res.push(fn(arr[i]));
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in [0...$scope.mealsList.length]{
            //if you want to delete some properties 'prop' form meaList object use this:
            //delete $scope.mealsList[i].prop0
            //delete $scope.mealsList[i].prop1
            data4.push($scope.mealsList[i])
}
```